# You can only access it from your registered IP address

Tags: ip, ip-address, mac-address

I have a basic question about Ip addresses. I have signed up for an online class that says "I can only access it from your registered IP address".

Does that mean I can only access it from the network I was using during my registration or I can access it anywhere from the same device?

Comment: From the wording, you may have an option to register more IP addresses as needed. Allowing only the IP address used during first registration would be bad for both technical and business reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Have to know a bit more to know how strict that rule might be.

Tentatively - yes, your IP is unique to the network you were using during registration.

However, you can generally install a VPN service and use your registration network's IP anywhere if you need to get around that limitation.

Comment: I am not sure how strict the rule is. Another question. you get the IP address from the network you are logged in to, right?

So I get a different ip address in my home network then another IP address at my work and so on, right?

Comment: @user3458037 Your IP is unique to the network you are connected to at the time. Yes - home and work would show you logging in from two different IP address.